# Is there a way to package jar dependencies for running the java class in a standalone environment

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

We have a small java based server (a simple app which fetches data using MySQL and hibernate) which needs to run standalone (e.g. `java -cp <....> com.foo.Server`).

Currently we use mvn for the entire build process and use `mvn exec:java` (http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) to run the application using maven.

We would like to package this application with its set of jar dependencies so that I can just use the command given above to run it on a production box (which will not have maven).

Database information present under META-INF\persistence.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.1:3306/foo/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="u1"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="u1pass"/>
```

1. How should I package this application or create a deployment image which I can deploy it on a production box.
2. How do I pass database credentials to this application in the production box. Currently the information is contained within the access jars (under META-INF\persistence.xml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple options to consider:

- Creating a JAR with dependencies in Maven
  [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)
- Application Assembler Maven Plugin
  http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/

Comment: I am fine with the assembler option to package the dependencies for [1]. Any pointers to solving [2]

Comment: Setting them in environment variables or a local properties file that is read by the app are common options for storing credentials or info that is specific the the server.

Answer (score 0):

There are various software to package the java application in market for example Installshield etc. You can also export you application as runnable jar file. I think all latest IDE support packaging the java application. Let me know which IDE you are using and I will try to answer your question specifically.

Comment: We are not using any IDE at the moment, just relying on mvn for the entire build lifecycle.